# Limit theorem for changed time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, martingales

This post seems long, but its almost everything proofed in this post. Only one step seems to be left, for the desired proof. I would be very gratefull for any help.

**The setup**
Given a Levy-Process $U_{t}$ with  with $E(U_t)=0$ (then $U_t$ is a martingale). Let $U_t$ have finite variance $Var(U_t)=tVar(U_1)$ and $Var(U_1)=\sigma^{2}$ and the limit theorem  holds:
\begin{align}
F_t:=\sqrt{t}\left(\frac{U_t}{t}-E(U_1) \right)=\frac{U_t}{\sqrt{t}}\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})\quad as \,\,t\rightarrow \infty.\tag1
\end{align}
Let $K_t$ a non-decreasing positive ($K_{t}>0$ a.s.) process with cadlag-paths with the property that $K_{t}\rightarrow \infty$ almost sureley, as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

I want to show that 
\begin{align}
F_{K_t}:=\frac{U_{K_t}}{\sqrt{K_{t}}} \xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})\quad as \,\,t\rightarrow \infty. \tag2
\end{align}
For this one requires a positive non-random cadlag-function $a(t)$ with $a(t)\rightarrow \infty$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ such that
\begin{align}
\frac{K_{t}}{a(t)}\rightarrow \theta\quad P\, a.s. \tag3
\end{align}
holds. Where $\theta$ is a positive random-variable.
Then the convergence in distribution of $F_{t}\xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$ implies the convergence in distribution of $F_{K_t}\xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$.

The original question from my old account is posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232921/functional-limit-theorem-under-random-change-of-time). 
However with my reputation here, i am able to start a bounty for the question.

**The suggestion of the proof are the following:**

For simplicity it is said, that $\theta=1$ and $\sigma^{2}=1$ So that we have $K_{t}\in ((1-\epsilon)a(t),(1+\epsilon)a(t))$ for large $t$. For $0<\theta<\infty$ we could do the same procedure and get the same result.

This is how we go on:
For small $m$ we have
$$
P(U_{K_t}<x\sqrt{K_t})\leq P\left(K_{t}\notin ((1-\epsilon) a(t),(1+\epsilon) a(t))\right)+P\left(U_{a_t}<x\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)a(t)}+m\cdot \sqrt{\epsilon a(t))}\right)+ P\left(\sup_{s\in ((1-\epsilon)a(t),(1+\epsilon)a(t))}|U_{s}-U_{a(t)}|>m\cdot \sqrt{\epsilon a(t))}\right)
$$
The first term converges to 0 due to (3). The second term converges to $\Phi(x+m)$ **(Why?)** by the central limit theorem (1) applied to $U_{a(t)}$.

The third term is bounded by martingale inequalitys $L^{2}$ by a factor
$$\frac{1}{(m\cdot \sqrt{\epsilon a(t))})^{2}}$$

Otherwise we can state
$$
P(U_{K_t}<x\sqrt{K_t})\geq Z\xrightarrow{d} \Phi(x-m)
$$
So we have sandwiched it and the **desired result (2) holds for arbitrary $0<\theta<\infty$.**

**HOWEVER (hopefolly the last step)** We have with $(3)$ convegence to a strict positive finite randomvariable $\theta$. **What is left to proof, considering, that $\theta$ is regarded as a random variable?**

Some additional stuffto understand the inequalities

$$
P(U_{k_t}<x \sqrt{K_t})\\
\leq P[U_{k_t}<x \sqrt{K_t},K_{t}\in((1-\epsilon) a(t),(1+\epsilon) a(t))]+P[U_{K_t}<x\sqrt{K_t},K_{t}\notin ((1-\epsilon) a(t),(1+\epsilon) a(t))] \\ \leq P[K_{t}\notin ((1-\epsilon) a(t),(1+\epsilon) a(t))]+ P[U_{k_t}<x \sqrt{K_t},K_{t}\in((1-\epsilon) a(t),(1+\epsilon) a(t))] \\
\leq P[K_{t}\notin ((1-\epsilon) a(t),(1+\epsilon) a(t))]  \\
+P(U_{K_{t}}<x\sqrt{(1+ \epsilon)a(t)},|U_{K_t}-U_{a(t)}|\leq m\sqrt{\epsilon a(t)},|U_{K_t}-U_{a(t)}|> m\sqrt{\epsilon a(t)}]
\\ \leq P[U_{a(t)}<x\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)a(t)}+m \sqrt{\epsilon a(t)}] + P\left(\sup_{s\in ((1-\epsilon)a(t),(1+\epsilon)a(t))}|U_{s}-U_{a(t)}|>m\cdot \sqrt{\epsilon a(t))}\right)+P\left(K_{t}\notin ((1-\epsilon) a(t),(1+\epsilon) a(t))\right)
$$

Comment: $K$ is independent of $U$, I hope?

Comment: @zhorastar well one can proof, that $(U_{t}/\sqrt{t},K_{t}/a(t))\xrightarrow{d} (Z,\theta)$ where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$ and $\theta$ defined as above are independent.

Comment: One cannot prove that for arbitrary $K$. So what is it?

Comment: What do you mean with "what is it?"

Comment: What is your $K$ for which you can prove this convergence?

Comment: @zhoraster  $K_{t}$ is just an increasing continuous process with values on $\mathbb{R+}$. It is used for a change of time change. For the convergence there are not more assumptions to be made, than the one stated above. Its more based on the Levy-property of the main process, for which the classical central limit theorems and random sum clt can be derived.   I actually tried another attempt here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809394/convergence-of-a-process       I'm almost done i hope. if you have any doubts about anything, i would be gladfull to hear. Thanks

Comment: @zhoraster but i dont see any restrictions why $K_t$ should be independent of $U$ for the case in the proof above.

Answer (score 1):

1. $(3)$ need not hold for general $K$. Say, set $K = t$ for half of $\omega$, and $K = t^2$ for another half. Then, depending on $a$, $\theta$ in $(3)$ will be either zero or infinite for half of $\omega$.
2. Without the independence assumption, the statement is false in general, even if $(3)$ is true. Specifically, let $U=W$ be a Wiener process and define $K_t$ to be a càdlàg modification of $\inf\{s\ge 0: W_s\ge t\}$.  By the self-similarity property of $W$, $(3)$ holds with $a(t) = t^{2}$.  ($K$ is even a Lévy subordinator: it increases and has independent stationary increments thanks to the strong Markov property of $W$.) However, $(2)$ cannot hold, obviously. (Moreover, it follows from self-similatity that $F_{K_t}= t/\sqrt{K_t}\overset{d}{=} 1/\sqrt{K_1}$.)
3. If $K$ is independent of $U$, then the statement is quite obvious. Indeed, denote $\varphi_s(u) = \mathsf{E}[e^{iu F_{s}}]$  the characteristic function of $F_s$. By $(1)$, $\varphi_s(u)\to e^{-u^2\sigma^2/2}$, $s\to\infty$, for any $u\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $\varphi_{K_t}(u)\to e^{-u^2\sigma^2/2}$, $t\to\infty$, a.s. On the other hand,
   $$
   \mathsf{E}[e^{iu F_{K_t}}] = \mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[e^{iu F_{s}}]|_{s=K_t}] = \mathsf{E}[\varphi_{K_t}(u)]
   $$
   thanks to independence. Then by the dominated convergence theorem, 
   $$
   \mathsf{E}[e^{iu F_{K_t}}] \to e^{-u^2\sigma^2/2}, t\to\infty,
   $$
   as claimed.

Comment: @ziT, do not hesitate to ask if something is not clear. I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: thanks for your help. Your edits are very usefull. I'm struggleling since convergence of (1) is mixing in the Renyi-sense. First one can show by donkser invariance principle for $s\in[0,1] : (U_t(s)/\sqrt{t})\xrightarrow{d} (W_s)_{s\in [0,1]}$ mixing. By Notation $U_{y}(s):=U_{y\cdot s}$. Then by Billingsley (convergence of probability measures) Theorem 17.2 one can show, that the mapping defined there one has $U_{K_t}(s)/\sqrt{K_t}\xrightarrow{d} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta}}W_{s\theta}\sim W_{s}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,s^{2}) $ since $\theta$ can be shown to be independent of $W$, due to mixing conv.

Comment: @ziT, I see, you in fact do assume (3). (BTW, I've misread this, seeing the convergence in distribution.) Then yes, there is indeed convergence by the cited theorem.